# Azure Terraform Error registering backup protection container for Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-backup-vault

I am using Terraform to create Azure Recovery Services Vault for File Shares. But it keeps reporting error:

```
Error: registering backup protection container StorageContainer;storage;fer-bpcm-d-rsg-commonsa;xxxbpcmpcgl (Vault fer-bpcm-p-euwe-rvt-golden): backup.ProtectionContainersClient#Register: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BMSUserErrorContainerIsAssociatedWithAnotherVault" Message="Container is associated with another vault. Please select the right vault to proceed with the container operation."

  with module.recovery_services_vault.azurerm_backup_container_storage_account.protection_container["fer-bpcm-p-euwe-rvt-golden~xxxbpcmpcgl~data"],
  on ../modules/LandingZone/BPCM/recovery_services_vault/main.tf line 75, in resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "protection_container":
  75: resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "protection_container" {
```

The terraform snippet is as below:

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "fs_rsv_vaults" {

  for_each                      = { for fs_rsv_vault in var.fileshare_recovery_vaults : fs_rsv_vault.name => fs_rsv_vault }
  name                          = each.value.name
  resource_group_name           = each.value.resource_group_name
  location                      = each.value.location
  # sku, immutability, storage_mode_type, soft_delete_enabled
  # public_network_access_enabled, cross_region_restore_enabled, tags,identity 
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_file_share" "rsv_vault_policy" {
  for_each            = { for policy in local.rsv_vault_policy_list : "${policy.vault_name}~${policy.policy_name}" => policy }
  name                = each.value.policy_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.fs_rsv_vaults[each.value.vault_name].resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.fs_rsv_vaults[each.value.vault_name].name
  # timezone, backup, retention_daily
}

resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "protection_container" {
  for_each = { for fileshare in local.fileshare_list : "${fileshare.recovery_vault_name}~${fileshare.storage_account_name}~${fileshare.source_file_share_name}" => fileshare }
  resource_group_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.fs_rsv_vaults[each.value.recovery_vault_name].resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = each.value.recovery_vault_name
  storage_account_id  = data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_accounts[each.value.storage_account_name].id
}
```

I checked [documetation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/backup_container_storage_account) But how to associate a unique protection container `azurerm_backup_container_storage_account` to each of the storage account since there is no `name` argument for protection container ? What is wrong I am doing?

I am passing list of Storage accounts like this:

```
fileshare_recovery_vaults = [
  {
    name = "myvault"
    resource_group_name = "rsg-backup" 
    ...
    backup_policies = [
      {
        policy_name = "policy-filesh"
        timezone = "UTC"
        backup_frequency = "Daily"
        backup_time = "00:00"
        retention_daily_count = 30
      }
    ]
    fileshares = [
      {
        storage_account_name = "xxxbpcmpcga"
        source_file_share_name = "data"
        resource_group_name = "rsg-commonsa"
        policy_name = "policy-filesh"
      },
      {
        storage_account_name = "xxxbpcmpcgl"
        source_file_share_name = "data"
        resource_group_name = "rsg-commonsa"
        policy_name = "policy-filesh"
      }
    ]
   ..
  }]
```

Comment: @VinayB I have a storage account which has blob storage which is being backup by Backup Vault and the same storage account has Fileshares which I trying to get backup by Recovery Services Vault. Is such scenario conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried registering backup protection container for Azure Storage Account & File Shares I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error you're encountering, `BMSUserErrorContainerIsAssociatedWithAnotherVault`, indicates that the storage container you're trying to register with the Azure Recovery Services Vault is already associated with another vault. This is a common issue when reusing storage accounts or containers that were previously associated with a different vault.

when I tired to link the a new Recovery service vault with a storage container which was already associated with another vault I faced the same Issue which you mentioned.

[image]

In Azure, a storage account container can only be associated with one Recovery Services vault at a time. If you try to associate it with a new vault without first disassociating it from the existing one, you'll encounter this error

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-recovery-vault"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_file_share" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-backup-policy"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name

  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }

  retention_daily {
    count = 10
  }
}

# Create storage accounts
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  for_each = { for sa in var.storage_accounts : sa.name => sa }

  name                     = each.value.name
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = each.value.tier
  account_replication_type = each.value.replication_type
}

# Create file shares with explicit dependency on storage accounts
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  for_each = { for fs in var.file_shares : fs.name => fs }

  name                 = each.value.name
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example[each.value.storage_account_name].name
  quota                = each.value.quota

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.example]
}

# Register the storage accounts with the Recovery Services Vault
resource "azurerm_backup_container_storage_account" "example" {
  for_each = { for sa in var.storage_accounts : sa.name => sa }

  resource_group_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name
  storage_account_id  = azurerm_storage_account.example[each.key].id
}

# Protect the file shares with explicit dependency on storage shares
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_file_share" "example" {
  for_each = { for fs in var.file_shares : fs.name => fs }

  resource_group_name       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name
  source_storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example[each.value.storage_account_name].id
  source_file_share_name    = each.value.name
  backup_policy_id          = azurerm_backup_policy_file_share.example.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_share.example]
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "storage_accounts" {
  description = "List of storage accounts to create"
  type = list(object({
    name             = string
    tier             = string
    replication_type = string
  }))
}

variable "file_shares" {
  description = "List of file shares to create"
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    storage_account_name = string
    quota               = number
  }))
}
```

##### terraform.tfvars:

```
storage_accounts = [
  {
    name             = "vksbstgacct1"
    tier             = "Standard"
    replication_type = "LRS"
  },
  {
    name             = "vksbstgacct2"
    tier             = "Standard"
    replication_type = "LRS"
  }
]

file_shares = [
  {
    name                = "vksb-file-share1"
    storage_account_name = "vksbstgacct1"
    quota               = 50
  },
  {
    name                = "vksb-file-share2"
    storage_account_name = "vksbstgacct2"
    quota               = 50
  }
]
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many storage accounts we can add to a Recovery Services Vault ? Does that mean I need to create `n` Recovery Vaults if I have `n` storage accounts ?

Comment: Here It's not the case with a storage account. You can use 1 storage account for n Recovery vaults all you need to do is we need to create n file shares containers for n recovery vaults in the same storage account.

Comment: Sorry, It not clear to me. I think protection containers are not same as fileshares or storage account blob containers. As per [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/backup_container_storage_account), protection container is part of Azure Recovery Services, not storage account. I am still unclear why I cannot add 2 SAs into `azurerm_backup_container_storage_account`.

Comment: Updated the code solution as per the requirement. Please check and confirm. Thanks!